# adding dynamicaly a form : The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android and I'm trying to create a registration form , the user should be able to add multiple users .

I created a layout containing the form , and tryed to add the form when clicking on the button , it worked for the first click and the app stopped on the second click to add one more form , , here his my code :

the fragment :

```
public static class NewCaseFragment extends Fragment {


        public NewCaseFragment() {
        }



        //EditText orgname;
        //EditText orgaddress ;



       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcase,
                    container, false);

            View formView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mform,
                    container, false);

            final LinearLayout formbis = (LinearLayout)rootView. findViewById(R.id.formbis);
            final RelativeLayout form1 = (RelativeLayout)formView. findViewById(R.id.formm);


            Button members= (Button)rootView. findViewById(R.id.members);
            members.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    RelativeLayout formtest = new RelativeLayout(v.getContext());
                    formtest = (RelativeLayout)form1;
                    //TextView tv1 = new TextView(v.getContext());
                   // tv1.setText("Show Up");
                    formbis.addView(formtest);
                }
            });


            return rootView;
        }
```

the form layout :

```
        android:id="@+id/formm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/fname"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
            android:hint="@string/lname"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/catspin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
            android:entries="@array/cat"
            android:prompt="@string/cat"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/rolespin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/catspin"
            android:entries="@array/role"
            android:prompt="@string/role"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/oparea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rolespin"
            android:hint="@string/oparea"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/job"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oparea"
            android:hint="@string/job"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/job"
            android:hint="@string/phone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

newcase.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/casename"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/casename"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- layout for organisation information -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/infoorg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="@string/infoorg"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/orgname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/orgname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/orgaddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/orgaddress"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/staff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="@string/staff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/form1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/fname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
                android:hint="@string/lname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/catspin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
                android:entries="@array/cat"
                android:prompt="@string/cat"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/rolespin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/catspin"
                android:entries="@array/role"
                android:prompt="@string/role"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oparea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rolespin"
                android:hint="@string/oparea"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/job"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oparea"
                android:hint="@string/job"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/job"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/formbis"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/members"
            style="@style/btnStyleGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/users2"
            android:text="@string/plus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            style="@style/btnStyleBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

here is the log :

```
05-11 16:17:25.947: W/dalvikvm(1614): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3344)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3215)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3172)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3152)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at com.pfe.risu.ManageActivity$NewCaseFragment$1.onClick(ManageActivity.java:207)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-11 16:17:25.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1614):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact I think that `formtest` has already `formView` as parent:

Here you declare that `form1` is a child of formView:

```
final RelativeLayout form1 = (RelativeLayout)formView. findViewById(R.id.formm);`
```

And then you set `formtest` as `form1`:

```
formtest = (RelativeLayout)form1;
```

And finally:

```
formbis.addView(formtest);
```

But here `formtest` cannot be attach to `formbis` because you already linked it to `formView` through `form1`.

Comment: I don't get it , because formtest gets attached to formbis when I click on the button for the first time . 
The application stops working on the second click to add the a second form ...

Comment: logcat added to my question